# How to prove it's not a manifold?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In $R^{3}$ , let $Y_{r}$ be the set of points at distance $r>0$ from the circle $C= \{ \left(x,y,z\right) ; x^2+y^2=1,z=0 \}$ i.e. a doughnut which may be too fat.

How to prove that when $r \geq 1$, $Y_{r}$ is not a smooth manifold?

It is intuitively correct since the point above origin is not $smooth$ there.
But if I directly parameterise it and show that it can't be differentiated, it only shows that this parameterisation does not work, how to prove in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch (for completeness, I added the case $r = 1$ per @CYC's comment):

**Case 1 (r > 1)**
At the point $p$ above the origin, you can show that there are $3$ linearly independent tangent directions, $2$ from one "sheet" of the parameterization and $1$ from the other. So, the tangent space $T_p Y_r$, and thus $Y_r$ itself, has dimension at least three. On the other hand, you can realize $Y_r$ as the level set of a function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ with full rank at most points on $Y_r$, so if $Y_r$ were a manifold, it would have dimension $2$, a contradiction.

**Case 2 (r = 1)**
In this case, the only problem point is the origin $0$. By the same argument as above, $Y_1$ must be a $2$-manifold. So, pick any local homeomorphism $\phi$ from a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $Y_1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$; we may assume $U$ is connected and (by intersection) contained in a ball of radius $< 2$ centered at $0$. Then, $U - \{0\}$ is disconnected but its homeomorphic image $\phi(U - \{0\})$ is connected, a contradiction.

Comment: What about $r=1$, the tangent space just fit there.

Comment: I found when r=1, the topology is wrong, since delete origin, it will be disconnect. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was helpful. I've written up case 2 for completeness (using your solution). Alternatively, one could show that $T_0 Y_1$ is actually $1$-dimensional, giving a contradiction in the other direction.